# Finding average of a variable based on the values of another variable in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset where there are two variables `A` and `B`.  Both have say 100 observations. The data is sorted based on `A` with ascending order. I need to find the average of `B` where the window of average is decided by `A`. Based on the first and last observations of `A`, the loop has to be run.

For E.g the range of `A` is 300-340.  Let `A(1)` denote the first value of `A`.  I need to run a loop which will break the moment the value `A` is `A(1)+2` i.e. 302.  The point is there may be more than 1 observation for each distinct value of `A`. For instance for values 300 and 301 of `A`, if there are 10 observations, I need the average of `B` for the corresponding 10 observations.

Similarly I need to run a loop from behind i.e. 340 (Descending loop).  For a value of A-5 (335) there could be 30 observations from the bottom.  For the corresponding 30 observations of `B` I need the average.

Comment: I think the answer may be very simple, but your question isn't clear enough.  Could you put in a sample of what the source data looks like and what the result should be?

Comment: Keith - Sample Data is as follows: 
A B
10 25
10 36
10 78
11 44
11 34
11 23
11 54
12 34
12 54
12 11
12 19
13 6

I need to find the Average of B.  I will run a loop which will pick the average of B when the values of A are 11 + some number (which is the first observation of A and which will be fixed for entire computation).  11+2 11+3 11+4 etc would be the condition.  When A's value is less than 13, for all the corresponding B's I need the average (for example).  The point is the first value of A is different for different data sets and therefore the code must pick the first value of A

Answer (score 0):

implement using proc sql

```
PROC SQL;

SELECT A, AVG(B)
FROM SAS-DATASETS
GROUP BY A
ORDER BY A DESC;
RUN;
```